# What is the difference b/w anonymous async function use and async function use

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to create a function "processArray(array)" that when called it will console.log item after item in the array with a delay of 1 sec between each log.
So I've managed to do so with this code (A):

```js
function delay() {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
    
    async function delayedLog(item) {
      await delay();
      console.log(item);
    }
    
    async function processArray(array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){ 
        await delayedLog(array[i]);
      }
    }
    
    processArray([1, 2, 3]);
```

But this code (B) doesn't work:

```js
function delay() {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
    
    async function delayedLog(item) {
      await delay();
      console.log(item);
    }
    
    function processArray(array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){ 
        (async () => {
        await delayedLog(array[i]);
     })();
      }
    }
    
    processArray([1, 2, 3]);
```

Why would B code not work? the only different is I've used an anonymous async function inside the for loop instead of declaring the processArray function async.

Comment: That Async IEFE creates a promise, but the loop doesn't wait for it.

Comment: You aren't `await`ing the result of the anonymous async function.